# Rotation of camera used for perspective projection

Tags: 3d, geometry, perspectivecamera

I am trying to perform a simple perspective projection of various 3D structures, defined as a plurality of 3D polygons (different z's), each comprising a plurality of points. The structure will be viewed by a number of different cameras that I define. These cameras are defined by placing a world camera(eye) at (0,0,z) in my world coordinates, look(0,0,0) and up(0,1,0) and rotating the world axes by alpha (about x-axis), beta(about y) and gamma(about z), thereby creating my local coordinates system for that particular camera. [I realise that I could do this with OpenGL but I want to try and do this myself and understand it, rather than using a black box]

The basis of my global camera is defined using the vectors u,v and w where w=(eye-look).normalised =(0,0,1); u=up.cross(w)=(1,0,0) and v=w.cross(u)=(0,1,0)

I am working with homogeneous coordinates so my transformation matrix for u_dashed,v_dashed,w_dashed looks as follows:

T(px,py,pz) = [1,0,0,px;0,1,0,py;0,0,1,pz;0,0,0,1] and R = [u,0;v,0;w,0;0,0,0,1]

so putting it all together I get

Tr=T(eye-look) x R' x R_zyx x R x T(-(eye-look)) where R' is the transpose of R and R_zyx is the combined forward rotation matrix (world => local coordinates)
I then multiply the orthogonal projection matrix (O) with the perspective transform matrix (P) (http://www.cs.uu.nl/docs/vakken/gr/Slides/06-projection.pdf) to determine the combined transformation:

C=O x P x Tr

Finally proj=(C x 4Dpoint) and do the perspective divide i.e. (proj.x/proj.w, proj.y,pro.w)

Or would I be better of determining the coordinates of each camera i.e. R_zyx x [0;0;z;1] and u,v and w by Rzyx x [ux,vx,wx,0;uy,vy,wy,0;uz,vz,wz,0;0,0,0,0]?

Comment: ...was there a question?

Comment: yeah forgot about that: It's in there now!

Answer (score 1):

okay I think I have understood it correctly now, but would welcome any comments/constructive criticisms.

Mv (view Matrix) (as defined here http://www.cs.uu.nl/docs/vakken/gr/Slides/06-projection.pdf)
   = T(eye-look) x R' x R_zyx x R x T(-(eye-look)) x T(-(eye-look))
   = [u',0;v',0,w',0;0,0,0,1]' x T(-(eye-look))

C = O x P x Mv

Then 4Dproj=C x [4Point]' and 
2Dproj = (4proj.x/4proj.w,4proj.y/4proj.w)

cheers